# Hide Rows Based on Check Boxes - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I'm trying to hide certain rows based on checkboxes that are checked in column 'C'.

Simply put if 'Option A' is checked, I only want to show rows 11 - 13, and row 22. If 'Option B' is checked. I only want to show rows 14 - 15, and row 22, etc.

I also would like to have them revert back after I uncheck. This is more of a learning exercise than anything, so I will get to 'checking multiple boxes' later.

I'm wondering if there should be some 'for' logic in there as well? I'm just not sure where...

Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated! Happy to get into more detail if need be.

Thanks a lot,

-M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- Run the script using `onEdit()`. This was mentioned by @I'-'I.
- Retrieve the values of all checkboxes.
- the rows which correspond to each checkbox are shown and hidden.

#### Modified script :

When you use this modified script,

- Please copy and paste this script to your script editor, and save it. When you check to the checkbox on the sheet, the rows are shown and hidden.

  - Before you use this script, please confirm that there are no `onEdit()` functions in your project.
- When you modify the cell of checkbox and rows, please set `cfg`. For example, when there is a checkbox at "C7" and the rows are from row 11 to row 13, please set `C7: {startRow: 11, endRow: 13}`.

Script :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cfg = { // Please set this object.
    C7: {startRow: 11, endRow: 13},
    C8: {startRow: 14, endRow: 16},
    C9: {startRow: 17, endRow: 19},
    C10: {startRow: 20, endRow: 21}
  };

  var activeRange = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var ranges = Object.keys(cfg);
  if (cfg[activeRange]) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues();
    values.forEach(function(e, i) {
      if (e[0]) {
        sheet.showRows(cfg[ranges[i]].startRow, cfg[ranges[i]].endRow - cfg[ranges[i]].startRow);
      } else {
        sheet.hideRows(cfg[ranges[i]].startRow, cfg[ranges[i]].endRow - cfg[ranges[i]].startRow);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

#### Note :

- In this modified script, if several checkboxes are true, the rows which correspond to each checkbox are shown.
- If you want to run the script at the specific sheet, please modify to `if (cfg[activeRange] && e.source.getSheetName() == "### sheet name ###") {`.

#### Rererence :

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit :

You want to show all rows without hiding, when users open the Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, how about this?

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var cfg = { // Please set this object.
    C7: {startRow: 11, endRow: 13},
    C8: {startRow: 14, endRow: 16},
    C9: {startRow: 17, endRow: 19},
    C10: {startRow: 20, endRow: 21}
  };
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("### sheet name ##");
  var ranges = Object.keys(cfg);
  sheet.showRows(cfg[ranges[0]].startRow, cfg[ranges[ranges.length - 1]].endRow - cfg[ranges[0]].startRow);
  sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).setValue(true);
}
```

- When you use this, please copy and paste it in your script editor.
- `onOpen()` can be used for running when the spreadsheet is opened.
- You can also use `cfg` as a global variable.
- When `true` of `sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).setValue(true);` is modified to `false`, when the spreadsheet is opened, all checkboxes are no check and all rows are shown.

Comment: Thanks for the response! You understood it perfectly. I'm just trying to run it in the current sheet I'm in. However, when I run the script above without specifying sheet name I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 9, file "Code")` . Line 9 is:  `var activeRange = e.range.getA1Notation();` I also replace the FIRST if `if (ranges.indexOf(activeRange) > -1 && e.source.getSheetName() == "API Calculator")` and got the same error on the same line.

Comment: @Marcus I'm sorry for the inconvenience. How did you run the script? When you run it by your script editor, such error occurs. Because this script uses ``onEdit()``, the script can be run by clicking checkbox on spreadsheet. Can you try to click the checkbox on spreadsheet?

Comment: Why go from the object to an array? `indexOf` is slow compared to using the bracket operator: `if (cfg[activeRangeStr])`

Comment: @Tanaike Sure thing. I actually was just debugging it. I'll save, then try the checkbox. Thanks! Edit: Worked! Question: I actually want all of them to be shown from the start. Can I alter in `var cfg`?

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your comment. Yes. I think so. So I updated my answer.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks a lot for all your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: @Nivi I'm glad your issue was solved. By the way, about your question in comment, you want to show all rows without hiding, when users open the Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike That is correct. When a user first opens the spreadsheet, and I want the user to see all rows if all boxes are unchecked.

Comment: @Nivi I added a sample script for showing all rows when the spreadsheet is opened. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177692/discussion-between-nivi-and-tanaike).

Answer (score -1):

```
function onEdit(e) {

    // Replace with the name of your sheet
    var sheetName = 'NameofYourSheet';

    // Align the trigger to the 4 checkboxes
    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != sheetName 
        || e.range.rowStart < 6 || e.range.rowStart > 11 || e.range.columnStart != 3) {
        return;
    }

    // Get checkbox values
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName),
        status = sh.getRange('C7:C10').getValues();

    // Crude helper func
    function showHideRow(v, i) {
        // [[row, numberRows]]
        var rows = [[11,3],[14,3],[17,3],[20,2]];

        return v[0]
               ? sh.showRows.apply(sh, rows[i])
               : sh.hideRows.apply(sh, rows[i])
    };

    status.forEach(showHideRow);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But, seem to be getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 7, file "Code")` Line 7: if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != sheetName

Comment: Ok, It works as expected with me. Did you change the sheetName to the string of name of sheet you are using? Thats the only reason I can think of. Best regards

Comment: It's a trigger function so do not run it direct from the script. It will work when chech / uncheck the boxes in 'C7:C10'

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to show all rows when all boxes are unchecked? Thanks a lot. What would I have to alter? Thanks