# Trying to understand what I am doing wrong in this onedit event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I found this onedit evene someone else posted on stack overflow, and I am trying to modify it to suit my purpose. I want it to hide/unhide several sections of rows with checkboxes at the top of each section. When I load it the first checkbox works properly, but the ones I add do not. I can add them to the function individually, but only one of them will work at a time. Here is the function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cfg = { // Please set this object.
    C7:  {startRow: 8, endRow: 22},
    C23:  {startRow: 24, endRow: 44}


  };

  var activeRange = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var ranges = Object.keys(cfg);
  if (cfg[activeRange]) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues();
    values.forEach(function(e, i) {
      if (e[0]) {
        sheet.showRows(cfg[ranges[i]].startRow, cfg[ranges[i]].endRow - cfg[ranges[i]].startRow);
      } else {
        sheet.hideRows(cfg[ranges[i]].startRow, cfg[ranges[i]].endRow - cfg[ranges[i]].startRow);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Would row groups work for you? You can set them up in the UI and use them to show and hide sets of rows with a single click, just like a checkbox

Comment: id prefer to be able to do it with checkboxes as im trying to make duplicate of a document that already exists in excell format I am trying to make this document as similar in function as possible.

Comment: I think a good place to start when using someone else's code is through proper attribution. You should include in your question the source of the code you are using, so that both you and future readers can understand the origins and intent of the code presented - including if said code is meant to be turn-key or simply an example to learn from.

Comment: The code is almost exactly as posted by a user named Tanaike in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757193/hide-rows-based-on-check-boxes-google-app-script I would have asked the question in that thread, but i cant post comments beause im a new user.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. At the question, I had supposed that the checkboxes are continuously arranged. In your case, the checkboxes are discontinuity arranged. So please modify from ``values.forEach(function(e, i) {`` to ``values.filter(String).forEach(function(e, i) {``. If this still didn't work, please tell me. I would like to think of about the issue.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for Thank you Very much for the help!!

Comment: Welcome. But I'm sorry for the inconvenience because of my incomplete answer.